# passing 2d array to function in c

Tags: c, arrays

I am passing this 2D array to function input(), but the compiler shows error. I am working with a user defined input. Where am i wrong?

```
#include<stdio.h>
int input(int array,int row,int column);
int main()
{
    int c,r;
    //getting input of c and r
    scanf("%d%d",&c,&r);
    int array2[r][c];
    //calling function
    input(array2,r,c);

}
int input(int array,int row,int column)
{
    int i,j;
    //taking input
    for(i=0;i<row;i++)
    {
        for(j=0;j<column;j++)
        {
             scanf("%d",&array[i][j]);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you are wrong here. you didn't tell the compiler that you are passing an array of integers! In the original signature you have declared a function `input` that takes 3 integer type by value!

```
int input(int array,int row,int column);
```

The function signature above is wrong! In your case (the dimensions of the 2D array is not available (either as a macro or as a global constant). so you need to declare `input` as below:

```
int input(int* array,int row,int column);
```

Or

```
int input(int array[],int row,int column);
```

Please review this post from geeks4geeks. its short and explaing all the methods for passing 2D arrays to functions and how you should declare the function correctly! [2D_array](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/pass-2d-array-parameter-c/)

Comment: Your final example, although it is possible to do manual indexing to do a 2D array [although the spec says no], it loses the 2D nature of caller's array. A better solution is the one proposed by user3121023

Comment: why better? `row` and `column` are not available at compile time ?! so i think the most accurate signature is the first one i wrote: `int input(int* array,int row,int column);`. if i am wrong please correct me

Comment: user3121023's solution is idiomatic. Because `row` and `column` are passed _before_ `array`, the syntax is supported for an arg. Although, in practice, a 2D array decays into an `int *` when passed as an argument, the ISO/C spec states that accessing a 2D array (e.g. `int array[100][3];`) fourth element via `array[0][3]` is UB. I disagree with the rationale for this, but ... And, in the function, with just `int *`, you have to do `array[(y * column) + x]` instead of `array[y][x]` (which you can do with the correct 2D argument).